# cat all lines from file, which are after "KEYWORD"

Tags: linux, bash, cat

I have a file, with a "KEYWORD" on line number n. How can I print all lines starting from line n+1 until the end?

For example, here I would liek to pro=int only lines DDD and EEE

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
KEYWORD
DDD
EEE
```

Comment: I could see this being really useful for log files with, say, something like a time stamp as the keyword.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do this with `sed`:

```
sed '1,/^KEYWORD$/d'
```

This will delete (omit) all lines from the beginning of the stream until "KEYWORD", inclusive.

Comment: For me this didn't work and I had to use `sed '1,/KEYWORD/d'`, instead. The context was a little different, but using `0,` would print the contents of the entire file, no matter what KEYWORD was.

Answer (score 3):

Use sed, printing from the KEYWORD match to the end of the file, then using tail to remove the KEYWORD line.

```
sed -n '/KEYWORD/,$p' file | tail -1
```

Comment: You probably mean `$` instead of `/$/`

Answer (score 3):

An alternative might be `grep` in combination with the `-A` flag, e.g.

```
grep -A10000 KEYWORD file
```

Where `10000` is just a big number to denoted the amount of lines until the end of the file, which for your practical daily use should be enough.

Otherwise you could use the amount of lines in the file as parameter like this

```
grep -A$(wc -l file | cut -d' ' -f1) KEYWORD file
```

But that is most likely overkill (and not easier to remember than the given `sed` alternative)

Comment: You'd need the `| tail -1` trick of @suspectus to omit the first line.