# How to get portion of lines from all .txt files in a directory?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have 5,000 text files of journal article citations. I am trying to extract only the abstract portion. Meaning that I want to keep the same text document and delete all the other text except for abstract. I am very new to Linux and I have been trolling your board for a while.

[how to extract words that after keyword](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80399/cat-all-lines-from-file-which-are-after-keyword)

[execute command on all file in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523415/bash-script-to-execute-command-on-all-files-in-directory)

```
for file in test
nano my.sh
while read variable do
  sed '0,/^Abstract$/d' 
done <file
```

Here is an example of a file its similar to a scientific journal article

```
Sponsor     : Beckman Res Inst Cty Hope
      1500 E. Duarte Road
      Duarte, CA  910103000    /   -

NSF Program : 1114      CELL BIOLOGY
Fld Applictn: 0000099   Other Applications NEC                  
          61        Life Science Biological                 
Program Ref : 9285,
Abstract    :
                                                                                         
          Studies of chickens have provided serological and nucleic acid                 
          probes useful in defining the major histocompatibility complex                 
          (MHC) in other avian species.  Methods used in detecting genetic               
          diversity at loci within the MHC of chickens and mammals will be               
          applied to determining the extent of MHC polymorphism within                   
          small populations of ring-necked pheasants, wild turkeys, cranes,              
          Andean condors and other species.  The knowledge and expertise                 
          gained from working with the MHC of the chicken should make for                
          rapid progress in defining the polymorphism of the MHC in these                
          species and in detecting the polymorphism of MHC gene pool within              
          small wild and captive populations of these birds.
```

Comment: Please give a sample of the file.

Comment: put sample data.

Comment: @jimmij I just edited the question. I put in example data.

Comment: It would also help if you would indicate what result you want from the sample text. Do you want to delete lines 1 through 10 (where line 9 is the one that says `Abstract` and line 10 is blank) and keep lines 11 (`Studies of chickens …`) through 21 (`… these birds.`)? Is line 21 the last line of the file? If not, how is the command supposed to identify the last line of the abstract? (E.g., is line 22 blank? Or does it contain some other constant heading string?)

Comment: @Scott I do not know what lines that this text portion is located. The text in these txt files can vary from author.

Comment: I know that you don’t know the line numbers in general; that’s why I said, “***from the sample text***” and referred to the sample text that you added to your question. I’m requesting that, ***for the sample text that you posted in your question***, you specify what results you expect.

Comment: @Scott Ohh. Alright gotcha. I'll keep that in mind for the future. And I'll edit my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to change a series of file in-place.  You want to delete all up to and including the first line that consists *in total* of `Abstract`.  If those files are in the current directory and are all named with a `.txt` extension, then use:

```
sed -i '0,/^Abstract$/d' *.txt
```

Since this will overwrite the old files and in case something goes wrong, don't use this without having a backup.

This may require GNU `sed` (which is standard on Linux).

#### How it works

- `-i`

  The `-i` option tells `sed` to edit files in-place.  The old file will be overwritten.
- `0,/^Abstract$/d`

  This command tells `sed` to delete (`d`) all lines from the first (number 0) up to and including the first line that matches the regular expression `^Abstract$`.  The caret, `^`, matches at the start of the line and the dollar sign matches at the end of the line.  Thus, this regex matches on a line that contains *only* the word `Abstract` with *no* other characters on the line.
- `*.txt`

  This tells the shell to select all files in the current directory that have the `.txt` suffix.

#### Update

This will delete all lines in each file up to the first line that *starts with* `Abstract`:

```
sed -i '0,/^Abstract/d' *.txt
```

Because the `$` has been removed, this regular expression only requires that the line begin with `Abstract`.

Comment: what does the -i mean? And your solution made all of my files blank.

Comment: @user3426338 `-i` means edit in-place.  It causes the old files to be overwritten with the new version. If you want something else to happen instead, let me know.

Comment: @Jon1024 yeah I am looking at the modified files through mousepad and all of my files are blank. I'm using backup files. I'm glad I took your advice on not using the original files.

Comment: @user3426338 My solution was based on the regex that you provided: `^Abstract$`.  I see from the updated question, that this is not a match to the sample input.  See the updated answer.  _And, continue making sure that you have  a backup._

Comment: So tried executing this command over a directory with countless sub directories. I looked at this manual about the  [find command](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm) and came up with this _sudo find / awd_1990_02 -name *txt -exec sed -i '0,/^Abstract/d' *.txt {} \;_  but I keep getting **sed: can't read *.txt: No such file or directory**

Comment: Figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```bsh
sed -ni.bak '/^Abstract/,$p' *.txt
```

Get all lines that starts`^` with `Abstract` to`,` end`$` of file and save a copy from original file named `*.txt.bak` by using sed's `-i` option.

With `awk`:

```bsh
awk '/^Abstract/,0' *.txt
```

If you want that also for sub_directory, use the command with `find` command like this:

```bsh
find /path/to/main-dir -type f -name "*.txt" -exec  sed -ni.bak '/^Abstract/,$p' '{}';
```

This is much better if you had a new line in file names:

```bsh
find /path/to/main-dir -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r file
do
    sed -ni.bak '/^Abstract/,$p' "$file";
done
```

---

In your given solution(`find -name *txt -type d -exec sed -i '0,/^Abstract/d' *.txt {} \;`) in body of your question you search for directories(`-type d` used for searching directories) which their names ends with `txt`, if you don't have any directory with same name as `*txt`, then your `-exec` part won't run. So you do nothing with that command.

So you have to change `*txt -type d` to `"*.txt" -type f`(this means all *.txt files`-type f` ) and quote them if your file names has spaces in it. And also you need to remove `*.txt` from end of `sed` command because `'{}'` in find command points to current file which is found and quote it too. Even it would be better if you specify path to find in command. Finally your tried command would be like following:

```bsh
find /path/to/main-dir -name "*.txt" -type f -exec sed -i '0,/^Abstract/d' '{}' \;
```

Comment: Thank you for all of you help.Do you know of any really good books or resources out there to get a better grasp of Linux and regex? Or does it just take practices?

Comment: You are welcome. 1[www.regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/), 2[Famous Sed One-Liners Explained, Part I: File Spacing, Numbering and Text Conversion and Substitution](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/), 3[http://linuxreviews.org](http://linuxreviews.org/beginner/tao_of_regular_expressions/), 4[Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), 5[https://www.cs.ucy.ac.cy/~dzeina/courses/epl371/lectures/06-sed.pdf](https://www.cs.ucy.ac.cy/~dzeina/courses/epl371/lectures/06-sed.pdf) and more on google search... ;)

Comment: @user3426338 I have updated answer for working on sub_directory.